# Excel If Statement to Return a text after evaluation

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, return-value

[Screenshot of the Excel Table.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W28mP.png)

In the First Accessed Data column there are Unix Enoch formatted dates which I turned into readable dates for Excel to convert into human readable dates. If a user never accessed the program the Unix Enoch number would be 0. The problem arises when I try to get the formula to return a certain value if the person never accessed the program.

I tried adding the IF function before the whole evaluation takes place and expected it to ignore the calculations since certain parameters have been passed.

```
=IF(G4=0;"Not Accessed")+(G4/86400)+DATE(1970;1;1)
```

Comment: Did you search on how to write an "If Statement"?

Comment: What you have written is equal to `=(G4/86400)+DATE(1970;1;1) + IF(G4=0;"Not Accessed")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `IF` is trying to add your calculation to the string `Not Accessed` if `G4=0`.  Hence your error.  Perhaps try:

```
=IF(G4=0,"Not Accessed",G4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1))
```

Comment: Flip man, how did I not realise that, I appreciate your help.